# warning: GC.stat keys for a ruby on rails app running in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just made pull of my app in github, 
In localhost i could create database: database:create and run migrations, when i try to run my local host, i have this error:

```
warning: GC.stat keys were changed from Ruby 2.1. In this case, you refer to obsolete `total_allocated_object' (new key is `total_allocated_objects'). Please check <https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9924> for more information.
```

When i go to https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9924 i see some codes, but i don't know what to do with these codes. 
Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: It is not an error, it's just a warning, which version of ruby do you have? maybe you need to upgrade to the mayor ruby 2.2 stable release so you can remove the warning.

Comment: But it stops the running of the app in localhost, and i have ruby 2.2: ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin13] This is the resto of mi local host running: [2015-08-02 21:20:53] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-08-02 21:20:53] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-darwin13]
Exiting
/Users/felipevelasquez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:206:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Comment: but your problem seems different `in 'bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE) ` maybe run this: `rails -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001` I think your mac already has a process owning that port

Comment: sorry the command is `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001` or another port, did that work?